# My characters walking animation breaks after jumping

Tags: animation, game-engine

When I test my game everything works perfectly until I jump. No animations except for the Idle one I have will work.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site, and I'm not really sure how to do that. I looked it up but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: You can throw em here http://www.pasteall.org/blend/